# Closed form for the sum $\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}{\left(n^2+m^2\right)^{-{p}}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, sums-of-squares

Is it possible to express the following sum in closed form?
$$S(p)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sum_{m=-\infty}^{\infty}{\left(n^2+m^2\right)^{\large-{p}}}$$
where the point $(n,m)=(0,0)$ is not taken into account in the sum (i.e. $(n,m)\in \mathbb{Z}^2/\{(0,0)\}$).

In the book *Lattice Sums Then and Now* by Borwein *et al.* it is stated (page 66, Appendix 1.7), that $S(p)=4\beta(p)\zeta(p)$, with $\beta$ and $\zeta$ the Dirichlet beta and Riemann zeta functions.

However I cannot find any derivation of this result. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\chi_4$ denotes the unique non-trivial [*Dirichlet character*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_character) modulo 4, then it is proved that for $k \geq 1$,

$$ r_2(k) := \#\{ (m,n)\in\mathbb{Z}^2 : m^2+n^2=k\} = 4 \sum_{d \mid k} \chi_4(d). $$

(I do not remember the proof of this fact, but the keyword [*sum of squares function*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SumofSquaresFunction.html) may be useful for finding out a reference.)

Now utilizing this, we have

\begin{align*}
S(p)
 = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{-p} r_2(k)
&= 4 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left( \sum_{d\mid k} \chi_4(d) \right) k^{-p} \\
&= 4 \left( \sum_{d=1}^{\infty} \chi_4(d) d^{-p} \right) \left( \sum_{l=1}^{\infty} l^{-p} \right)
 = 4 \beta(p)\zeta(p).
\end{align*}

Comment: I believe there is a misprint in the first expression: the sum should be over $d\mid k$.

Comment: @user355705, Thank you, I fixed the typo.

Comment: Nice and simple proof +1. The proof for sum of squares function can be provided by using [Jacobi elliptic/theta functions and their Fourier series](http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/02/elliptic-functions-fourier-series.html), and there is also a pure number theoretic proof but don't remember any reference for it.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh, Thank you for the informative comment. As for the number-theoretic proof, now I faintly remember that this is related to factorization in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.